# Linux bash command with quotes - inside quotes - inside quotes

Tags: linux, bash

I have this command that runs fine - 
`mysql -p$DB_PW -u ops --host="$DB_ENDPOINT" -e "delete from users.webservers where ipaddress='$PRIVATE_IP';"`

I want to run it with a different user so I have to put the command inside single quotes but it then will now work -

`sudo -H -u ernie bash -c 'mysql -p$DB_PW -u ops --host="$DB_ENDPOINT" -e "delete from users.webservers where ipaddress='$PRIVATE_IP';"'`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Observe: `a=1; echo "$a"` and `a=1; sudo bash -c 'echo "$a"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second layer of quotes (`"`) will have no problems being nested inside `'` quotes. Your most nested layer must be escaped. To escape single quotes, use

```
'\''
```

instead of `'`

Technically, this is not escaping single quotes, this is ending the previous quoted section, writing a literal `'`, and then starting a new quoted section. This is how bash is designed to handle single quotes that must be nested inside other single quotes.

Comment: That little tidbit made sense of it all. Thanks!

Comment: @ErnieVanDuyne, consider accepting one of the answers on your question if they have resolved it satisfactorially. You can do this by clicking the grey checkmark under the voting buttons. You should also probably go back and do this on previously asked questions. You'll get some rep for doing this and it will let others know that you question has been answered and they don't need to spend time trying to decide if it needs more help.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to run `bash`; `sudo` will run `mysql` just fine.

```
sudo -H -u ernie \
    mysql -p"$DB_PW" \
          -u ops \
          --host="$DB_ENDPOINT" \
          -e "delete from users.webservers where ipaddress='$PRIVATE_IP';"
```

Note that there is a risk of a SQL injection attack; be sure you know what the value of `PRIVATE_IP` is before executing this command.